# Android - Radio button automatically indented

Tags: android, radio-button

I just added `android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` to my radio button. But it indented automatically.

[image]

Why? Is there any property to solve this?

```
 <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/question"
        android:id="@+id/rg">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/choice0"
            android:scaleX="0.75"
            android:scaleY="0.75"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:text="choice0" />

   ...
```

In my adapter, I set this value. I didn't change any ui properties through adapter code.

Comment: post your xml, where is your aaaaaaa.......

Comment: @TarunVarshney I am setting value through adapter. I will post my row item xml

Answer (score 0):

Try setting either the `android:layout_gravity` of each of the `RadioButtons` to `"start"` or the `android:gravity` of the entire `RadioGroup` to `"start"` and see if that aligns it better.

Answer (score 0):

Cause for the issue:

```
android:scaleX="0.75"
android:scaleY="0.75"
```

I added these properties to reduce radio button size. But when text length increases, it automatically indented. I removed these properties and now it looks aligned